# Why does Rails 3 think xE2x80x89 means â x80 x89

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicode, utf-8, utf-16, multibyte

I have a field scraped from a utf-8 page:

```
"O’Reilly"
```

And saved in a yml file:

```
:name: "O\xE2\x80\x99Reilly"
```

(xE2x80x99 is the [correct UTF-8 representation of this apostrophe](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm))

However when I load the value into a hash and yield it to a page tagged as utf-8, I get:

```
OâReilly
```

I looked up the character â, which is encoded in UTF-16 as x00E2, and the characters x80 and x89 were invisible but present after the â when I pasted the string. I assume this means my app is outputting three UTF-16 characters instead of one UTF-8.

How do I make rails interpret a 3-byte UTF-8 code as a single character?

Answer (score 2):

Ruby strings are sequences of bytes instead of characters:

```
$ irb
>> "O\xE2\x80\x99Reilly"
=> "O\342\200\231Reilly"
```

Your string is a sequence of 10 bytes but 8 characters (as you know).  The safest way to see that you output the correct string in HTML (I assume you want HTML since you mentioned Rails) is to convert non-printable characters to HTML entities; in your case to

```
O&#x2019;Reilly
```

This takes some work but it should help in cases where send your HTML in UTF-8 but your end-user has set his or her browser to override and show Latin-1 or some other silly restricted charset.

Comment: I'll bear this in mind, but I need to store the utf-8 string in the database.

Comment: Not to worry, the database stores the UTF-8 byte sequence.  Ruby 1.9 helps a bit.  Does this link help? http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_string

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately this was caused by loading a syck file (generated by an external script) with psych (in rails). Loading with syck solved the issue:

```
#in ruby environment
puts YAML::ENGINE.yamler => syck

#in rails
puts YAML::ENGINE.yamler => psych

#in webapp
YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck'
a = YAML::load(file_saved_with_syck)
a[index][:name] => "O’Reilly"
YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'psych'
```

Answer (score 1):

> I assume this means my app is outputting three UTF-16 characters instead of one UTF-8.

It's not really UTF-16, which is rarely used on the web (and largely breaks there). Your app *is* outputting three Unicode characters (including the two invisible control codes), but that's not the same thing as the UTF-16 encoding.

The problem would seem to be that the YAML file is being read in as if it were ISO-8859-1-encoded, so that the `\xE2` byte maps to character U+00E2 and so on. I am guessing you are using Ruby 1.9 and the YAML is being parsed into byte strings with associated ASCII-8BIT encoding instead of UTF-8, causing the strings to undergo a round of trancoding (mangling) later.

If this is the case you might have to `force_encoding` the read strings back to what they should have been, or set `default_internal` to cause the strings to be read back into UTF-8. Bit of a mess this.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that xE2 also maps to â in iso-8859-1. Thanks.