# Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0 UTF-8 madness

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, utf-8, character-encoding, irb, latin1

My [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616229/why-does-rails-3-think-xe2x80x89-means-a-x80-x89) is answered but there's a few more things I don't understand.

I have a yaml file which contains a field with a utf-8 character:

```
:name: O\xE2\x80\x99Reilly
```

When I load the yaml in irb:

```
>puts name.encoding => UTF-8
>name => "O\xE2\x80\x99Reilly"
>puts name => O’Reilly
```

When I load the yaml in Rails:

```
>puts name.encoding => UTF-8 
>puts name => Oâ[80][99]Reilly
>puts name.force_encoding('utf-8') => Oâ[80][99]Reilly
>puts Iconv('iso-8859-1', '', name) => O’Reilly
```

Q3: Why does rails print it's initial utf-8 string as if it's iso-8859-1, and the string converted to iso-8859-1 as if it's utf-8?

Answer (score 1):

Your `config/application.rb` file in rails probably has this:

```
config.encoding = "utf-8"
```

This is only an answer to the first Q and may or may not have any relevance to the next 2 :)